# Is there a way to know that window film is what it's advertised?

Tags: window, film

Is there a way to know that you're getting the window film that you were told it'll be?

E.g., if I'm interested in an 78% Visible-Light-Transmission ceramic film with 43% Total Solar Energy Rejection from LLumar, or 71% VLT and 48% TSER from Hüper Optik USA, is there a way to ensure that I'm not instead getting some kind of a knock-off, e.g., a dyed or metallised tint instead, or a ceramic with lower VLT?

I'm probably interested in purchasing a precut kit from the internet or possibly a local shop in Austin, TX.  Are there any kind of labels or certificates that are generally provided together with the films?

What about 3M?  They seem to have a *Precision Fit Program*, which offers "Pre-cut, pre-shrunk window tint kits" as *3M™ Precision Fit Kits*, but they only appear to advertise it for dealerships; is there a way to just purchase the kit directly?  And if there is, what kind of packaging would it have to ensure that the kit is authentic?

Comment: IMHO, if you want to get authentic, find a dealer. I would think anything you get off of the internet is suspect. The tint which was on my Camaro had tint which was done in TX. It had a little sticker placed under the tint on the driver's side which stated the VLT value on it. It was supposed to be certified at that level. I can tell you the application was done perfectly, so I didn't doubt the sticker. I don't have a real answer for you on this. Hopefully someone with some experience will pipe in.

Comment: In my experience, all 3M products will have "3M" printed on the peel-off backing.

Comment: @kmarsh, actually, that's a good tip!  but what about the more intricate details, like the type of the film and the VLT spec?

Comment: Sorry that's all I got. :(

Comment: @kmarsh, thinking more about it, the type, spec and production year/week must also be printed in some kind of a small print in certain places on some parts of the peel?

Comment: Usually, especially with brand-names. However what is printed there is often the OEM brand, and not the retail vendor's name. Comparing notes with someone who has actually used the product would help (probably why you are here lol).

Comment: @kmarsh, and I *am* looking for the OEM brand, aren't all the brands mentioned the OEM brands?  I certainly don't care what the local retailer calls the ceramic film from LLumar or some such, as long as I know what LLumar calls it. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the window market enough to answer the question. But typically, familiar auto brands subcontract production to a company that specializes in film, since it is specialty manufacturing.